# Unite number of UIimageView to one

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I have a couple of UIImageViews on top of eace other, lets say i want to save all of them a single image.
Is there a way to "screenshot"/ connect all of the UIImageView to one ?

So then i could use:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mv.frame.size);
[[mv layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Thank You.

Comment: Did you try that? Did you try drawing multiple layers into the context?

Comment: Try to embed all the image views in a single `UIView` as its subviews and try the above code on its layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by making a screenshot about the superview of all `UIImageView`. I wrote a method for this: (be sure you added your `UIImageViews` to the same view.  for example:

```
[self.view addSubview: image1];
[self.view addSubview: image2];
[self.view addSubview: image3];
[self.view addSubview: image4];
```

then make a screenshout about `self.view`
)

```
+ (UIImage*) screenShotTheArea:(CGRect)area inView:(UIView*)view{

        if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(area.size.width, area.size.height), NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
        else
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size);

        CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextTranslateCTM(c, -area.origin.x, -area.origin.y);
        [view.layer renderInContext:c];
        UIImage* thePrintScreen = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        return thePrintScreen;
    }
```

Comment: In your method i need to pass self.view.
but if i want just the area of the imageView that contains above more imageView? what do i do then?

Answer (score 1):

if you want a fast and easy approach take a screenshot of the view that holds your images

```
- (UIImage *)screenShot:(UIView *)aView {
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[aView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
CGContextSetRGBFillColor (UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0, 0, 0, 0.4f);
CGContextFillRect (UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), self.view.frame);
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return image; }
```

and get it with:

```
UIImage *screenshot = [self screenShot:self.view];
```

Good Luck!!